# Nginx rewrite all requests from exapmel.com/xx/y.php to non example.com/y.php

Tags: php, nginx

I need to redirect all request for php files regardless of the subpath

so eg.

```
example.com/xx/y.php or example.com/xx/anotherpath/yy.php
```

it should remove /xx/ from the path

so it should rewrite to

```
example.com/y.php or example.com/anotherpath/yy.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out below code :)

```
server {
  ...
  location ~ /.+/.+/.+\.php {
    rewrite /.+/(.+)/(.+)\.php /$1/$2.php break;
  }

  location ~ /.+/.+\.php {
    rewrite /.+/(.+)\.php /$1.php break;
  }

  location ~ .*\.php {
    ##your php processing code
  }
  ...
}
```

You need to maintain the order of the above location blocks.